# In Excel how can a formula verify whether the column location or column element has taken the correct data from its header name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**The Input data**

[image: Data] 
 in sheet1

and

the **output** calculated in sheet2

[image]

Now the sheet1 data can be changed by the user for input, so now  **columns 'Units1' & 'Units2' may not be placed at the same address that are in columns 'C' and 'D' respectively, so suppose a new user will input the data in which 'Avocado' and 'Banana' are in columns C & D , then the 'Output' calculation in Sheet2 will be incorrect because we always want to use Units1 & Units2 for calculation.**

How to fix this, so that every time the data is input the formula checks whether the correct columns have been taken for calculation or not?

Is there a way to use INDEX or family of LOOKUP functions or any other function for this.

Maybe by a creating a new sheet and making a table of Indexes which refer to (or point to) the column names of Data sheet

| Location | Dates | Units1 | Units2 | Avocado | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 05-01-18 | 10 | 12 | 1 | 2 |
| Los Angeles | 02-02-18 | 20 | 23 | 1 | 2 |
| Chicago | 08-03-18 | 30 | 34 | 1 | 2 |
| Houston | 05-04-18 | 40 | 45 | 1 | 2 |
| Phoenix | 02-05-18 | 50 | 56 | 1 | 2 |
| Philadelphia | 08-06-18 | 60 | 67 | 1 | 2 |
| San Antonio | 05-07-18 | 70 | 78 | 1 | 2 |
| San Diego | 02-08-18 | 80 | 89 | 1 | 2 |
| Dallas | 08-09-18 | 90 | 99 | 1 | 2 |
| San Jose | 05-10-18 | 100 | 112 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Turn the list in sheet1 into a [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c). Refer to its data using [structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

Comment: @GSerg thanks for sharing this suggestion. Is there a way we can do this using INDEX and LOOKUP functions?

Comment: [Two-way lookup with INDEX and MATCH](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match#two_way_lookup) | very tempted to write this (with example details) as answer.. but the original site explains it _way_ better... hands up) /(^_^)

Comment: btw `Xlookup` is [available](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function) for 365. (I didn't have that version installed to test/testify)..

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thanks a lot for sharing these helpful resources. And yes XLOOKUP also worked right for my objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(2:2,1,MATCH("Units2",$1:$1,0))/INDEX(2:2,1,MATCH("Units1",$1:$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: If you are not sure, whether the locations are in the same order, you can adjust the formula like this: `=INDEX($A:$F,MATCH($I2,$A:$A,0),MATCH("Units2",$1:$1,0))/INDEX($A:$F,MATCH($I2,$A:$A,0),MATCH("Units1",$1:$1,0))`.

Comment: @Qualia I tried using this formula but I need to put text criteria instead of I2 and when I tried that then I'm getting value error, could you help me with that?
Basically I'm trying to make a dynamic template so that even if the column values change, the formula will look for header name and perform operation, so in this case the formula should divide Units2 by Units1 by checking the column header and not just the cell address because if someone modifies data then cell address of Data sheet will change and we'll get incorrect value.

Comment: @Qualia I replaced I2 with "Units2" and "Units1" in the formula and got value error.
Also, tried making the Data sheet into a table format and used structured references but then I got reference error for some reason I don't know why

Comment: @Qualia Hey, sorry I figured it out, it was some typo error earlier, now it's fixed. However I have another question, I'm getting Value Error when I'm trying to write a new formula based on your suggested Index-Match format, Formula :
 =(Data!C3-INDEX(Data!3:3,1,MATCH(MIN("Units1"),Data!$1:$1,0)))/(((INDEX(Data!3:3,1,MATCH(MAX("Units1"),Data!$1:$1,0)))-INDEX(Data!3:3,1,MATCH(MIN("Units1"),Data!$1:$1,0)))*10)

Comment: Your usage of `MIN` and `MAX` does not seem correct to me.

Comment: @Qualia could you please suggest how to use it correctly then?

Comment: @Qualia I need to use the formula in the way that , (current cell value - MIN of whole range of that column) / ((MAX of that column - MIN of that column)*10) , so that it is scaled between 0 and 10 , min max scaling

Comment: But you are not doing it that way. You use the string parameter "Units1" in `MIN`. '=MIN("Units1")' will always result in a #Value! error. You would have to wrap MIN around the desired range. However, the comment section is not sufficient to solve it. Thus, I recommend to ask another question which should include the table with your sample data as well.